# Why to use the extra slash (/) at the end of the Django urls?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm trying to create a REST API using Django. I'm currently implementing the `urls.py` file. In a lot of different examples, I saw that they add `/` at the end of the url. For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'),
]
```

I'm trying to figure way. Surely for `login` POST request which returns a token (given username and password), you want to access `<domain>/api/login` and not `<domain>/api/login/`. Currently I solved it with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'login$', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'),
]
```

Or:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'),
]
```

But what is the convention? Why a lot of different examples add the extra `/` at the end? When do you want to add it?

Answer (score 4):

Django's [`CommonMiddleware` tries to normalize URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware), so that every URL exists only once, not in a version ending with slash and one without. Therefore the user doesn't have to care about appending a slash or not, also for search engines this is a big win as they don't see the same content with different URLs.
You can configure this behaviour either with the [`APPEND_SLASH` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-APPEND_SLASH) or the [`no_append_slash()` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.common.no_append_slash).

Comment: This might be a thing in the browser world. But REST urls ending with a / are pretty weird, if not to say incorrect.